# Create Doctrine query

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a quiz application where played rounds are logged in `UserPerformanceEntity`. The corresponding MySQL table looks like:

```
UserPerformance
---------------
id (PK)
user
start_time
end_time
max_level
```

I want to display some statistics, like 'You performed better than x% of players'. To calculate the percent of players who performed worse than the current I want to execute the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`)
FROM `UserPerformance`
WHERE 
  (end_time IS NOT NULL
  AND end_time NOT LIKE '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
  AND `user` != :current_user
  AND max_level < :current_level
ORDER BY max_level DESC
```

But I have no idea how to implement this with doctrine. How should my querybuilder look like?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$query->select('COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) as usercount')
    ->where('u.end_time IS NOT NULL')
    ->andWhere('u.end_time NOT LIKE :end_time')
    ->andWhere('u.id != :current_userid')
    ->andWhere('u.max_level < :current_level')
    ->setParameter('end_time', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    ->setParameter('current_userid', $current_userid)
    ->setParameter('current_level', $current_level)
    ->setMaxResults(1);

$result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
return $result[0]['usercount'] ;
```

The only change is, you need id from current user instead object

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me to find the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Additional information that a user can play many times, so user id is not unique, one user can have many records. This is my solution:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $result = $qb->select('COUNT(DISTINCT p.user) AS usercount')
            ->from('LoginetFBappVagoBundle:UserPerformanceEntity', 'p')
            ->where(
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->isNotNull('p.endTime'),
                    $qb->expr()->neq('p.endTime', ':endTime')))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq('p.user', ':userId'))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->lt('p.maxLevel', ':maxLevel'))
            ->setParameter('endTime', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
            ->setParameter('userId', $userid)
            ->setParameter('maxLevel', $level)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

I started from @Alexander Keil's answer, but I used expressions, and I figured out that there is no need to group the `(end_time IS NOT NULL AND end_time NOT LIKE '0000-00-00 00:00:00')` part. However if I pass `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` in the expression instead setting as a parameter, I get an error. And at last I have to count the distinct users the get the correct result.